# Почему не работают звонки WebRTC из firefox в хром?

Tags: webrtc

Firefox не может дозвонится в chrome, хотя если звонить наоборот из хрома в фаерфокс, то все прекрасно работает. Все это дело происходит на одной машине.
Причем никаких ошибок не выдается в консоль. Событие `onaddstream` срабатывает, и даже в тег `video` записывается `src=polyblob:2` , но ни звук, ни видео не показываются.
Еще заметил в отладчике webrtc хрома `(chrome://webrtc-internals/)` последнее событие `iceconnectionstatechange`, когда коннектишься из firefox в хром, секунд через 5-10 становится красным и снизу вместо `complete` выдает `failed`.